# Eclipse, cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This is from a textbook about App-Development.

```
import java.awt.TextField;

public class ESA
{
    public void init()
    {
        TextField abc = new TextField();
    }
    public void doSomething()
    {
        abc.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The Problem is: There is one Error in the code, an there should be a way to solve it with Eclipse. No solution is given the textbook.

In my opinion, the problem is "abc.setText" 
Eclipse has 6 quick fixes, but none of them work.

Has anyone an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TextField` variable `abc` is not available in the scope of the method `doSomething` as it is defined locally in `init`. It can either be declared as a class member variable or passed into the method. You could add

```
private TextField abc;
```

and replace

```
TextField abc = new TextField();
```

with

```
abc = new TextField();
```

[Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.TextField;

public class ESA
{
    private TextField abc;
    public void init()
    {
       abc = new TextField();
    }
    public void doSomething()
    {
        abc.setText("Hello World");
    }
}
```

This should work. `abc` is not accessible in the `doSomething()` of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I come across this question because I worked on the same problem, perhaps the same textbook.

So that's the reason why I want to answer this question even when it is already two years old.

"... there should be a way to solve it with Eclipse. No solution is given the textbook."

The  easy way that is ment here is the "Refactoring". Right click on "abc" and then choose "Refactor" and in the submenu "Convert Local Variable to Field".

All needed changes in the code will be done by Eclipse on its own. The resulting code is the same that is here already posted in the other solutions.